# pyWin32 support? Trouble while building; syntax error

Tags: python, installation, pywin32

I just downloaded pyWin32 (https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) and started to install it.

My first question: does anybody know, where I can get specific pyWin32-support? I can't see/find anything at sourceforge.

2nd question: Did anybody of you encounter the problem, that h2py.py ran into an syntax-error during installation?

I get this msg:

```
C:\Users\someone\pywin32-214>python setup.py build  
Building pywin32 2.6.214.0  
running build  
running build_py  
running build_ext  
Found version 0x600 in C:\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\include\SDKDDKVER.H  
Skipping exchange: No library 'Ex2KSdk'  
Skipping exchdapi: No library 'Ex2KSdk'  
Skipping directsound: The header 'dsound.h' can not be located  
building exe 'pythonservice'  
building exe 'Pythonwin'  
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe /nologo /f makefile_pythonwin SUB_DIR_O=C:\Users\Benni\Desktop\pywin32-214\build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\scintilla SUB_DIR_BIN=C:\Users\someone\pywin32-214\build\temp.win32-2.6\Release\scintilla DIR_PYTHON=C:\Python26

C:\Python26\tools\scripts\h2py.py Include\scintilla.h  
File "C:\Python26\tools\scripts\h2py.py", line 134  
exec stmt  
^  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax  
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Python26\tools\scripts\h2py.py": return-value "0x1"  
Stop.  
error: command 'nmake.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

But when I look into the mentioned h2py.py I can't see any syntax-error (of course!! :-) )

So, has anybody any idea how I could cope with this? That'd be great! :-)

TIA
Ben

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need to build?  Why not just install the pre-built binaries by downloading and executing  `pywin32-214.win32-py2.6.exe` ?  It works perfectly for me.

Comment: Hello Don! Thanks a lot for your answer!! I just was too attracted by the big green download-box. :-( ;-)